# I'm trying to access a certain element inside a .json url but I keep gettin an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, parsing

For example, this is part of the json file output:

```js
{
      "ein": 205477787,
      "strein": "20-5477787",
      "name": "1 BYTE COMPUTER LITERACY INC",
      "sub_name": "1 BYTE COMPUTER LITERACY INC",
      "city": "WILMINGTON",
      "state": "NC",
      "ntee_code": "B60",
      "raw_ntee_code": "B60",
      "subseccd": 3,
      "has_subseccd": true,
      "have_filings": null,
      "have_extracts": null,
      "have_pdfs": null,
      "score": 1.0
    },
```

and I am trying to output "name" into the python terminal with this code:

```py
import requests
import simplejson as json

response = requests.get("https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/api/v2/search.json")

json_test = response.json()

json_str = json.dumps(json_test, indent=2)
print(json_str[0]['name'])
```

but I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

How can I solve this?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen So if i remove it, How would the new code look like that will output the name of the .json url. Should it be print(json_test['name'])?

Comment: I've put it in an answer.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Oh thank you! Now last question. How would I output every single name in the file, instead of just the output of index 0 "0 TOLERANCE INC"

Comment: you can print them in a loop or create a list of the names with list comprehension: `[i['name'] for i in json_test['organizations']]`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `json_str = json.dumps(json_test, indent=2)` as `json.dumps` outputs a string. You have already loaded the json with `response.json()`. Also, you missed the key `objects` in the `print` function.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/api/v2/search.json")

json_test = response.json()

print(json_test['organizations'][0]['name'])
```

Output: `0 TOLERANCE INC`

Answer (score 0):

Using this code:

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

count = 0
response = requests.get("https://projects.propublica.org/nonprofits/api/v2/search.json")

json_test = response.json()

for i in json_test:
    i = count
    print(json_test['organizations'][i]['name'])
    count = count + 1
```

I get the following output

```
0 TOLERANCE INC
0003 POSTAL FAMILY
0005 GA
0005 WRIGHT-PATT CREDIT UNION
0011 CALIFORNIA
0022 HOMELAND CREDIT UNION INC
005 HELENA
0053 IH CREDIT UNION
007 BENEFIT LTD
0083 K J BRANCH ST JOSEPHS SOCIETY
01420 INC
0197 UNIVERSAL 1 CREDIT UNION INC
```

the loop iters through the name keys in the dictionary